# Can physicist estimate is it safe to walk/drive on ice?

Tags: everyday-life, estimation

I'm curious about the following: Suppose that I know the the weather forecasts of a given place. How can I compute from that data whether or not it is secure to walk or drive by a car to an island.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about human safety.

Comment: Oh well. So how can I estimate that without using physics?

Comment: I'm sure there are models for estimating the relative danger / accident rates based on weather patterns.  Those are off topic for this site though.

Answer (score 1):

Friction experiments are really difficult to carry out. You would have to know the material of the road. You'd have to define what is *secure* and what is not as well...

For instance, dust on the road changes a lot the friction coefficient. So I would answer: don't try to compute how *secure* it is to walk or drive given some weather forecast because your calculations will contain a lot of error.